# Is there a way to find the largest change in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to find the largest difference between i and j in a series where i cannot be before j. Is there an efficient way to do this in pandas:

```py
x = [1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 7]
largest_change = 0

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(x)):
        change = x[i] - x[j]
        print(x[i], x[j], change)
        if change > largest_change:
            largest_change = change
```

The output would just be the value, in this case 4 from 5 to 1.

Comment: i should not be before j. So taking the max - min will not work. The actual data has date associated with it so I'm looking for the largest change between the start date to end date.

Comment: Shouldn't the largest different be the last two values in the list? From 1 to 7? _Or are you looking for the index of this value change?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try numpy broadcast with `np.triu` and `max`

```
arr = np.array(x)
np.triu(arr[:,None] - arr)

array([[ 0, -1, -4, -3, -1, -3, -1,  0, -6],
       [ 0,  0, -3, -2,  0, -2,  0,  1, -5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  3,  1,  3,  4, -2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,  2,  3, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -2,  0,  1, -5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  3, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1, -5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -6],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

np.triu(arr[:,None] - arr).max()

Out[758]: 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides Andy's smart method, here is another one propagating the minimum value backward whose advantage is to have linear time complexity, instead of quadratic, in case you handle a large amount of data.

```
a = np.flipud(np.array(x))
largest_change = (a - np.minimum.accumulate(a)).max()
```

Comment: it's nice to see another numpy solution :) +1

Comment: I like this solution. Could this be done in constant space?

Comment: @evan-brittain To do that in constant space efficiently, I'd go for the numpy [ufunc.reduce](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) approach but the processing here is too specialized for the built-in ufuncs and the custom ufuncs created with [frompyfunc](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html) are not compiled to native code on-the-fly so they don't have better performance than their original python functions. To go further I think you'd need a numpy extension implementing a custom ufunc in C.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
x = [1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 7]
largest_change = 0
position = 0

for i in range(len(x)-1):
    change = x[i] - min(x[i+1:])
    if change > largest_change:
        largest_change = change
        position = i

print(x[position], min(x[position+1:]), largest_change)
```

Comment: Thought so too, but then I reread the code, I think Evan wants the largest difference in kind of one direction

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just take the `diff` then the max of that?

```
x = [1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 7]
s = pd.Series(x)

z = abs(s.diff())
idx_max_val = z[z==z.max()].index[0]

print(f'Max difference in value ({z.max()}) occurs at the indices of {idx_max_val-1}:{idx_max_val}')
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest rolling window:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 7]})
df["diff"] = df['col1'].rolling(window=2).apply(lambda x: x[1] - x[0])
print(df["diff"].max())
```

Output: `6.0`

Or did I misunderstand you and you just want the largest difference between any two values?
This would be:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 7]})
max_diff = df["col1"].max() - df["col1"].min()
print("Min:", df["col1"].min(), "Max:", df["col1"].max(), "Diff:", max_diff)
```

Output:

```
Min: 1 Max: 7 Diff: 6
```

Comment: This checks only adjacent elements.