# Is there a way to find the largest continuous change in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to return the largest continuous increase, as well as the largest continuous decrease in a pandas dataframe column. For example, if the array is:

x = [1, 2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 5, 4, 5, 1]

The output for the largest increase would be 6 [3 to 9],
The output for the largest decrease would be 5 [9 to 4].

Since 1,2,6,3,5,9 is not continuously ascending, the largest increase would not be 7.

Likewise, since 9,5,4,5,1 is not continuously descending, the largest decrease would not be 8.

This is similar to a question that has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58985747/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-largest-change-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column) The solution given is very elegant - though I am not sure that will be as easy for this situation. Any ideas would be great!

Comment: Although this is a fun coding question, as written it is off-topic since you are simply requesting code rather than asking for help fixing code. Please rewrite your question to include your attempt at solving the problem, otherwise, this question will probably be closed.

Comment: for increase, `s.groupby(s.diff().lt(0).cumsum()).agg(["first", "last"]).diff(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].max()`. for decrease, can substitute -s in lieue of s. Since no effort on your part, I won't make an effort to explain this :) Maybe it doesn't even work.

Comment: Please [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Tl;dr you have to show your work. You can't just post a set of requirements and then ask the Community to solve it (well you *can* but that typically leads to downvotes, closure, and deletion fairly quickly)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 6, 3, 5, 9, 5, 4, 5, 1])
```

`s`

```
0    1
1    2
2    6
3    3
4    5
5    9
6    5
7    4
8    5
9    1
dtype: int64
```

**Code**

```
s1 = s.diff()
grouper = s1.mul(s1.shift()).lt(0).cumsum()
out = s1.groupby(grouper).sum()
```

`out`

```
0    5.0
1   -3.0
2    6.0
3   -5.0
4    1.0
5   -4.0
dtype: float64
```

get your desired output

```
>>> out.max()
6.0

>>> out.min()
-5.0
```

---

**Intermediate**

`s1` is the difference between the value in s and the immediately preceding value. The value of `grouper` changes when the sign of s1 changes.

------`s1`------`grouper`---

```
0   NaN         0
1   1.0         0
2   4.0         0
3   -3.0        1
4   2.0         2
5   4.0         2
6   -4.0        3
7   -1.0        3
8   1.0         4
9   -4.0        5
```

Comment: The OP showed no work, and only posted a set of requirements. It's off-topic as written - they provided no [mcve] - no code, no errors, no specific question. Please don't answer such questions (plus the question has already been closed, meaning this answer will along with the question once it's deleted)

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you very much for your help [PandaKim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20430449/panda-kim) ! This was my first time posting, and I apologize for not supplying sample code. It didn't occur to me to provide the code that I had already tried since it didn't actually work. I will make sure to fulfil the requirements next time.

Answer (score -1):

well a very elegant using pandas way is to use these three functions for series:

```
pandas.Series.diff() 
pandas.Series.idxmax() 
pandas.Series.idxmin()
```

Comment: The OP showed no work, and only posted a set of requirements. It's off-topic as written - they provided no [mcve] - no code, no errors, no specific question. Please don't answer such questions (plus the question has already been closed, meaning this answer will along with the question once it's deleted)